# Is angle in between two angles

Tags: math

I have 3 angles a b c

a=315
b=20
c=45

ok so would like to know giving all three if b is in between a and c

i have the long way of doing this adding and subtracting that's seems to work. I would just like to get something smaller and maybe more efficient.

thanks

EDIT

Here is a picture what i am trying to say.

[image]

Ok I have angle L(currently 0) i add 45(or any angle) and subtract 45(or any angle) to get a and b (my view angle).

Now i need to know if the green dot is between a and b

(g> a || g > 0) && (g < b)

so in this picture only the top green dot will be true..

Sorry if I am not making my self clear my first language is not English

Comment: What do you mean by "in between"? Testing whether either `a > b > c` or `a < b < c`, or something more sophisticated?

Comment: e.g. if you have 0, 120, and 240 degrees, which angle is between which other two and why?

Comment: HI in the example the statement will be true. 20 lies between 315 and 45.What i want to do is i have a angle d i want to determine what i can see if my view is 45 both ways. so if i look at 0 degrees i add 45 and i subtract 45 thats how i got a and c b is a object i want to check

Comment: @Pintac Hey, I upvoted your question because it seems useful. But I'm disappointed to see that the answer you have accepted is wrong, as I point out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236848/is-angle-in-between-two-angles/42424631#comment71953706_10237006 I'd appreciate if you'd unaccept the incorrect answer.

Comment: You tell about three angles a, b, c; you draw three lines A, B, L and place four dots. How do you expect us to follow this ??

Comment: @Zéychin I just wanted to say thank you for deleting the incorrect answer. Even if we can't get a correct answer accepted, at least the accepted one isn't wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Those are given cases for what `g` might be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating if an angle is between two angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234574/calculating-if-an-angle-is-between-two-angles)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I got it. All the calculations are in degrees.
I needed to calculate id a gps location is inside a rectangle.

Or, I needed to see if an angle `x` is between angle `check+r` and angle `check-r`.

`check-r<x<check+r`.

If you need `a<x<b`, find the angle `check` in the middle of `a` and `b` and then the distance (`r`) of `check` from `a` or `b`.

The method normalize, changes the angles from -infinity...infinity to -180...180.
The method check, takes the arguments
`x`: the angle that we need to see if it is between the angles check-r and check+r.
`check`: the angle to check with.
`r`: the radius around angle check.

```
private static double normalize(double x) {
        x = x % 360;
        if (x>=180) {
            return x-360;
        }
        if (x<-180) {
            return x+360;
        }
        return x;
}
public static boolean check(double x, double check, double r) {
        x = x - check;
        x = normalize(x);
        return x<r && x>-r;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1<sup>st</sup> off, every angle is between 2 other angles, what you're really asking is:

## For given angles: *a*, *b*, and *g*, is *g* outside the reflex angle between *a* and *b*?

You can just go ahead and define *a* as the leftmost angle and *b* as the rightmost angle or you can solve for that, for example if either of these statements are true *a* is your leftmost angle:

1. *a ≤ b ∧ b - a ≤ π*
2. *a > b ∧ a - b ≥ π*

For simplicity let's say that your leftmost angle is *l* and your rightmost angle is *r* and you're trying to find if *g* is between them.

The problem here is the seem. There are essentially 3 positive cases that we're looking for:

1. *l ≤ g ≤ r*
2. *l ≤ g ∧ r < l*
3. *g ≤ r ∧ r < l*

If you're just defining *a* to be leftmost and *b* to be rightmost you're done here and your condition will look like:

```
a <= g && g <= b ||
a <= g && b < a ||
g <= b && b < a
```

If however you calculated the *l* and *r* you'll notice there is an optimization opportunity here in doing both processes at once. Your function will look like:

```
if(a <= b) {
    if(b - a <= PI) {
        return a <= g && g <= b;
    } else {
        return b <= g || g <= a;
    }
} else {
    if(a - b <= PI) {
        return b <= g && g <= a;
    } else {
        return a <= g || g <= b;
    }
}
```

Or if you need it you could expand into this nightmare condition:

```
a <= b ?
(b - a <= PI && a <= g && g <= b) || (b - a > PI && (b <= g || g <= a)) :
(a - b <= PI && b <= g && g <= a) || (a - b > PI && (a <= g || g <= b))
```

Note that all this math presumes that your input is in radians and in the range [0 : 2π].

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/iwbMqZ)

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the suggested solutions when handling negative angles (e.g. from=30 to=-29)

**The suggested (kotlin) fix should be:**

```
fun isBetween(from:Float,to:Float,check:Float,inclusive:Boolean = true):Boolean{
   var a1 = to - from
   a1 = (a1 + 180f).mod(360f) - 180f
   if(a1<0f) a1+=360f

   var a2 = check - from
   a2 = (a2 + 180f).mod(360f) - 180f
   if(a2<0f) a2+=360f

   val between = if(inclusive)  a2<=a1 else a2<a1 && a2>0f
   println("$from->$to, $check, $between ($a1,$a2)")
   return between }
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally had the same problem recently and found counterexamples for all the answers posted yet, so I will share my own approach.
Let `a` be the start angle and `b` the end angle and we are checking whether `c` is between them clockwise, that means when you go from `a` to `b` you must pass `c`. The approach of checking whether `c` is in the range from `a` to `b` gives you false positives when `b` is greater than `a` numerically. For example:
`a=80°, b=320° and c=150°: a <= c <= b` which would mean that `c` is between `a` and `b`.
But it isn't.
The approach that's working is to subtract 360 from `b` if it is greater than `a` and also subtract 360 from `c` if `c` is greater than `a`. Then check whether `a <= c <= b`.
In Java:

```
public static boolean isBetween(double c, double a, double b) {
    if (b > a) b -= 360;
    if (c > a) c -= 360;
    return a <= c && c <= b;
}
```

This assumes that a, b and c are in range 0 to 360.
Some example:

```
isBetween(150, 80, 320) => false
isBetween(30, 80, 320) => true
isBetween(340, 80, 320) => true
isBetween(140, 0, 160) => true
isBetween(180, 0, 160) => false
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `a > c`, you would actually use:

```
( b < a ) && ( b > c )
```

This is the same as checking if a value is between a lower and upper bound. Them being angles makes no difference, unless you want to take into account the fact that as you go round a circle, an angle of `405` is the same as an angle of `45`. In which case you can just use `a % 360` to get the angle betweeen `0` and `360`.

Comment: hi yes the only problem comes if i check across 360. then is just not checking hight and low read comment at top.

Comment: In a circle, any angle will lie between any two other angles. Draw it out and you'll see that.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `a = 350`, `b = 355`, `c = 5`.