# create a circular list by using a range of angles python

Tags: python, range, circular-list

I have a list of lists which contains the lower and upper limit of sets of angles

something like

[[1,22],[2,24]...[359,15],[360,21]]

360 elements in total

Now I want to check for each angle from 1 to 360 the elements in the list that contains that angle

I was thinking about using the lower and upper limits to create all the elements of the list with `range` or `np.arange(lower,upper)` and check if the angle is contained, but `np.arange` generates empty list when lower is higher than upper

```
for i in range(1,361):
    sel=[]
    for coe in coef:
        if i in range(coe[0],coe[1]):
            sel.append(coe)
```

I tried also with `itertools` and `cycle` but i do not see how it can be applied in this case

Comment: won't all elements eventually be included in sel if you are looping through all the possible angles?

Answer (score 6):

The standard way to do this is to use modulus. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892476/4014959) by sschuberth shows how to do this in C/C++.

Here's a Python implementation and test. The code is simpler in Python, because in Python `a % b` always has the same sign as `b`.

The test code loops through all pairs of angles from 0 to 360 degrees in steps of 60, for `a` and `b`, testing all angles `x` from 0 to 360 degrees in steps of 30. The sector starts at `a` and sweeps through to `b`. Thus the sector (60, 120) contains 60°, but (120, 60) contains 300°.

If `x` is within the sector (including the endpoints) it gets added to the `result` list.

```
def in_angle_interval(x, a, b):
    return (x - a) % 360 <= (b - a) % 360

# test 

for a in range(0, 420, 60):
    for b in range(0, 420, 60):
        result = [x for x in range(0, 390, 30) if in_angle_interval(x, a, b)]
        print('{:3}-{:3} {}'.format(a, b, result))
```

**output**

```
  0-  0 [0, 360]
  0- 60 [0, 30, 60, 360]
  0-120 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 360]
  0-180 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 360]
  0-240 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 360]
  0-300 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 360]
  0-360 [0, 360]
 60-  0 [0, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
 60- 60 [60]
 60-120 [60, 90, 120]
 60-180 [60, 90, 120, 150, 180]
 60-240 [60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240]
 60-300 [60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300]
 60-360 [0, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
120-  0 [0, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
120- 60 [0, 30, 60, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
120-120 [120]
120-180 [120, 150, 180]
120-240 [120, 150, 180, 210, 240]
120-300 [120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300]
120-360 [0, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
180-  0 [0, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
180- 60 [0, 30, 60, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
180-120 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
180-180 [180]
180-240 [180, 210, 240]
180-300 [180, 210, 240, 270, 300]
180-360 [0, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
240-  0 [0, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
240- 60 [0, 30, 60, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
240-120 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
240-180 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
240-240 [240]
240-300 [240, 270, 300]
240-360 [0, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360]
300-  0 [0, 300, 330, 360]
300- 60 [0, 30, 60, 300, 330, 360]
300-120 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 300, 330, 360]
300-180 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 300, 330, 360]
300-240 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 300, 330, 360]
300-300 [300]
300-360 [0, 300, 330, 360]
360-  0 [0, 360]
360- 60 [0, 30, 60, 360]
360-120 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 360]
360-180 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 360]
360-240 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 360]
360-300 [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 360]
360-360 [0, 360]
```

---

And here's a test using the data in the question.

```
coef = [[1,22], [2,24], [359,15], [360,21]]
print(coef)
for x in range(0, 361):
    sel = [coe for coe in coef if in_angle_interval(x, coe[0], coe[1])]
    if sel:
        print('{:3} {}'.format(x, sel))
```

**output**

```
[[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
  0 [[359, 15], [360, 21]]
  1 [[1, 22], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
  2 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
  3 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
  4 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
  5 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
  6 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
  7 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
  8 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
  9 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
 10 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
 11 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
 12 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
 13 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
 14 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
 15 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [359, 15], [360, 21]]
 16 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [360, 21]]
 17 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [360, 21]]
 18 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [360, 21]]
 19 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [360, 21]]
 20 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [360, 21]]
 21 [[1, 22], [2, 24], [360, 21]]
 22 [[1, 22], [2, 24]]
 23 [[2, 24]]
 24 [[2, 24]]
359 [[359, 15]]
360 [[359, 15], [360, 21]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a customized compare function?

```
    def compare(angle, lower, upper):
        if lower <= upper:
            return lower <= angle and angle <= upper
        else:
            return ((angle >= lower and angle <= 360)
                    or (angle <= upper and angle >= 1))
```

Then test if the angle is in any of the intervals:

```
    >>> angle
    3
    >>> intervals
    [[1,22],[2,24]...[359,15],[360,21]]
    >>> any([compare(angle, *interval) for interval in intervals])
    True
```