# Determine if Angle is Between 2 Other Angles

Tags: c#, math, xna, trigonometry

I've seen a few answers, but I'm a little unsure of a C#/XNA-specific implementation.

I have the following:

```
var targetAngle = 0.2f;
var min = 0.8f;
var max = -0.98f;
```

Right now, I'm just using

```
targetAngle > min || targetAngle < max
```

But from what I understand, because angles in XNA are betwen PI and -PI, and wrapping, this won't work. I've also tried this statement from this question here [Is angle in between two angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236848/is-angle-in-between-two-angles)

```
if ((max - min) % Math.PI > 0 && targetAngle > max && targetAngle < min)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask what you are doing here? It looks from the names of your variables you are trying to turn an object and restrict the amount it can rotate? If this is true you should have a start angle also?

Comment: do you mean 'targetAngle > min && targetAngle < max'

Comment: @Sayse: I'm actually trying to create a new sprite, but only if the rotation of another sprite is within the allowed bounds.

Comment: @vc 74: I've tried it both ways, just cause, with no luck.

Comment: @Jack So min and max are always in [-Pi, Pi] but targetAngle can be any double value, right?

Comment: @vc 74: Well, in theory, target angle is the rotation value of a sprite, so it should be within those bounds, too.

Comment: It would seem to me like your min/max values are the wrong way round, I had the same thought as vc but with greater than max and less than min - `targetAngle > max && targetAngle < min` but you already try this slightly in your second code example?

Comment: Yeah, using the second method always returned false. Using the first, I was able to get it working when the bounds were set to something like Pi/2 and -Pi/2.

Comment: why your max is negative and your min is positive?

Comment: B/c I tried reversing the min and max on the second code piece, but it still returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think of it a different way. First, how to define the outer angle? You have `min` and `max` there. If that actually means minimum and maximum as the variable names infer, it's quite easy. If your angles are between `-Pi` and `+Pi`, just normalise the values first by adding `2*Pi` to anything less than 0, then check if `targetAngle` is between the two as you have already done. eg:

```
 public bool IsBetween(float min, float max, float targetAngle)
 {
     var normalisedMin = min > 0 ? min : 2 * Math.PI + min;
     var normalisedMax = max > 0 ? max : 2 * Math.PI + max;
     var normalisedTarget = targetAngle > 0 ? targetAngle : 2 * Math.PI + targetAngle;

     return normalisedMin <= normalisedTarget && normalisedTarget <= normalisedMax;
 }
```

So in your example normalisedMax would roughly equal `-0.98 + (3.14 * 2)` = `5.30`, thus the target angle is not between.

Alternately you could assume you are instead intending to take the smallest possible distance between the two outer angles, in which case `max` could actually be a lower value than `min` and still be valid for testing. In that case you just need to see if the distance from the target angle to either of those other angles is more than 90 degrees. If yes, the target is outside the defined angle. If both are less than (or equal, depending on how you define your edge cases) 90 degrees, the target angle is inside. e.g:

```
public bool IsBetween(float a, float b, float targetAngle)
{
    const float maxDistance = (float)Math.PI * 0.5f; // 90 degrees

    return Math.Abs(MathHelper.WrapAngle(a - targetAngle)) < maxDistance
        && Math.Abs(MathHelper.WrapAngle(b - targetAngle)) < maxDistance;
}
```

These are intentionally simplistic examples for demonstration purpose. Usual caveats about optimisation, float precision etc apply.

Comment: The second answer is definitely the one I need, though I'm having a little trouble understanding/implementing it. In my case, I'm giving -MathHelper.PiOver2 as the max and -MathHelper.PiOver2 as the min. In this case, should an angle (say 0) not return true? And also, why is maxDistance a constant at Pi/2?

Comment: This does work, however, if I change the return statement to say 

return Math.Abs(MathHelper.WrapAngle(min - targetAngle)) < maxDistance
                && Math.Abs(MathHelper.WrapAngle(max - targetAngle)) > maxDistance;

Comment: Sorry typing on a phone at the moment but not sure I get the comment. The second comment's code looks the same as I posted except min=a and max=b. Am I missing something? And why maxDistance's value: it doesn't really matter what that value is as long as, for whatever unit of measurement you're using, it equals a right angle / 90 degrees. So if you're measuring as a whole circle is 360 degrees the max angle you'll accept is one quarter of that i.e. 90. If measuring a circle as 2*Pi radians, then the max angle you'll accept in those units is one quarter of 2*Pi radians, i.e. 0.5*Pi radians.

Comment: I switched the less than to a greater than on the second conditional in the return statement.

Comment: If you go with solution 1, then you need to also wrap the angle, or just remove the if check and always add Pi*2 (or 360 if using degrees) to keep your min and max as it is.  As it stands right now, doing it this way could flip your min to max if your min < 0 and your max > 0

Comment: Nice catch @Knight0fDragon!