# Three.js OrbitControls with azimuth close to +/-180 degrees

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a situation where I use an OrbitControls to have a limited view in a room/space. The OrbitControls gets min/max values for azimuth and polar angles to control the view.
The OrbitControls' target is close by the camera to achieve the correct view, compare to the "panorama / cube" example (https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cube#webgl_panorama_cube).

In one situation this works fine. In an other situation this does not work. The reason is that because of the placement of objects, the starting azimuth is -179.999 degrees.
I have not found a way to tell the orbitcontrol to have the azimuth between -179.999 +/- 20 degrees.

I have experimented a little with the algorithm of @Αλέκος ([Is angle in between two angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236848/is-angle-in-between-two-angles?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and it looks like I can calculate the correct angles (not fully implemented). For that I would have set an azimuth and a delta in stead of min/max (and change the OrbitControls code).

Any suggestions for an easier solution? Thanks!

Test code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var orbitControls;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors
});

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);

// colors
red = new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0);
green = new THREE.Color(0, 1, 0);
blue = new THREE.Color(0, 0, 1);
var colors = [red, green, blue];

console.log("FACES", geometry.faces.length)

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    geometry.faces[4 * i].color = colors[i];
    geometry.faces[4 * i + 1].color = colors[i];
    geometry.faces[4 * i + 2].color = colors[i];
    geometry.faces[4 * i + 3].color = colors[i];
}

geometry.faces[0].color = new THREE.Color(1, 1, 1);
geometry.faces[4].color = new THREE.Color(1, 1, 1);
geometry.faces[8].color = new THREE.Color(1, 1, 1);

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.position.x = 0;
cube.position.y = 4;
cube.position.z = 44;
console.log("CUBE", cube.position);
var cubeAxis = new THREE.AxesHelper(20);
cube.add(cubeAxis);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.x = 0.8;
camera.position.y = 4.5;
camera.position.z = 33;

orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
orbitControls.enablePan = false;
orbitControls.enableZoom = false;
orbitControls.minPolarAngle = (90 - 10) * Math.PI / 180;
orbitControls.maxPolarAngle = (90 + 10) * Math.PI / 180;

// These values do not work:
orbitControls.maxAzimuthAngle = 200 * Math.PI / 180;
orbitControls.minAzimuthAngle = 160 * Math.PI / 180;

orbitControls.target.x = 0.8;
orbitControls.target.y = 4.5;
orbitControls.target.z = 33.1;

orbitControls.enabled = true;

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if (orbitControls) {

        orbitControls.update();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    // console.log("orbitControls", "azi", orbitControls.getAzimuthalAngle() * 180 / Math.PI);
};

animate();
```

Comment: Try `scene.rotation.y = Math.PI`, instead, and keep your azimuth within [ - PI, PI ]. Camera can't be added to the scene if you use that trick, though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Rotating the scene works in the example (although the cube is further away), but it does not in the "real" project (which has a large 3D model).
I'll try to use a different way to set the azimuth range.